# Substitute username/password with new iOS 5 Accounts.framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, oauth, ios5

In the [iOS 5 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_0/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010949) the Accounts.framework is mentioned:

> Accounts Framework
>   The Accounts framework (`Accounts.framework`) provides a single sign-on model for certain user accounts. Single sign-on improves the user experience, because applications no longer need to prompt a user separately for login information related to an account. It also simplifies the development model for you by managing the account authorization process for your application. In iOS 5.0, applications can use this framework in conjunction with the Twitter framework to access a user’s Twitter account.
>
> For more information about the classes of the Accounts framework, see [Accounts Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011024).

To my understanding this is not the equivalent of the Keychain on the Mac, which can store username and passwords, but it uses [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) which seems to work  with a token for authentication, rather than a username and a password.

Now the points I am not certain about:

1. If I want to make use of the Accounts framework do I have to change the Authentication mechanism on my server backend. If yes, do I need some sort of OAuth plugin on the server side?
2. Assuming that this is the case and that I have control over the server backend, how do I have to process the password, so that it can be stored in the Accounts framework.
3. Are the accounts iCloud compatible so that if I log in on an iPad could I automatically be signed in on my iPhone too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key line here is

> In iOS 5.0, applications can use this framework in conjunction with the Twitter framework to access a user’s Twitter account.

As it stands, you cannot use the Accounts framework with your own accounts. It is there solely for use with the Twitter framework. It's a seperate framework so that in the future it can be opened up to this kind of use (*or any further integration Apple provide, such as Facebook perhaps*).

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with micpringle. Accounts Framework should be able to persist a user account. It should work without Twitter framework. It is essential to use Accounts Framework if single sign on is desired. I'll test it out and update my answer.